# The frame count getted from FFmpeg is different from its splitting action result?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I had executed these two commands, and I got confused by its unconsistent result.

1. I got frame count through the command following:

   > ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 FPS30-536-CFR.mp4

   The result is 536.
2. I fetched every frame and saved it to a directory:

   > ffmpeg -i FPS30-536-CFR.mp4 ./frames/out%04d.jpg

   I got 537 pictures in the `./frames` directory which numbers form `0001.jpg` to `0537.jpg`

I had tried another video, the two results are maintained the same.

Please give me some hints, thank you very much.

[Here is the video.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aVSG5-9upl-C6F2hEA-V_kaax-ZkhOwj)